# a very confusing(personally) question about integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been doing integration from $5$ days so i know very basic integrations trigonometric and exponential. So my question is whether $$\int \sqrt {\tan x dx}$$ and $$\int \sqrt{\tan x}dx$$ the same i dont think so but how to integrate $$\int {\tan x dx}$$ is it integrable if yes then how?

Comment: I'd say the first expression is meaningless.

Comment: $\int \sqrt{\tan x dx}$ is meaningless. The $dx$ is apart of the antiderivative operator.

Comment: So is it geometrically incorrect to be dx under root

Comment: The integral sign comes from the old-fashioned letter  S for sum. As in  Sum   $ f(x_j)(x_{j+1}-x_j)=$ Sum$ f(x_j) d(x_j) $  being approximately a definite integral.